# Change default filter display

Tags: kibana

I am using filter as shown in the manual here...

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html

The problem is that only the top 5 buckets are shown in this list. I need to go to "Visualize" tab to get the complete picture. Is it possible to increase the count from 5 to 10?

---

Update:

My version of kibana does not have "visualize" button as shown in this image...

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to edit filter and add `size=10` option to query?

Comment: Tried. But that does not change the default behavior of showing only 5 buckets. I guess this should be a added as a feature request?

Comment: @shantanuo What do you mean by `5 buckets`? Where are you applying filter in `discover` page or `visualization` page?